# windows 7 and 10 wont install on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, installation, 64-bit, reinstall

so I had a little oopsie with chkdsk and it screwed up system 32. so I tried to reinstall windows 7 profesionall 64 bit but now the thing fails while expanding the files with [thiss error comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zdpk.png). I'm not sure if my Rufus settings are wrong or not but I've tried windows 10 and 7 both fail about halfway through the install. I get an error saying the install cant complete. I have an SSD with Windows 7 pro 64 bit that works perfectly fine and nothing is wrong with the one I'm trying to install windows onto(its litteraly less than a mounth old). [My rufus settings are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgfLe.png).
I'm not sure if something is wrong here or with my settings or if it is possibly the flash drive I'm using or the iso file which I got from Windows7 USB DVD Download tool Installer. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 and Windows 10 are you working with? Home, Pro, Enterprise, Education, or other? Are they all 32-bit or all 64-bit? Please click [edit] and add that info to your original question; please do not reply by Comment.

Comment: Run a hard drive test, the drive may be failing.

Comment: moab its an ssd and its brand new ive had it less than a week

Comment: `Boot selection: MS-DOS` means that you want to create a drive that boots MS-DOS. That's completely different from a Windows installation drive. As Ramhound has pointed out below, your settings are clearly wrong. You need to click on the `SELECT` button to select your Windows installation ISO and make sure the name of that ISO is displayed under _Boot selection_.

Comment: The error indicates a problem with the ISO you are using.  Download it again and use the correct Rufus settings per my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if something is wrong here or with my settings

You are using incorrect settings.  Your current settings would require you to configure your system to support [UEFI:NTFS](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs)

I suggest you just use different settings which will be compatible with your system without much effort on your part.  You can also just use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) and it will create a working installation disk for you.  If you have to create a Windows 7 installation disk then you must use Rufus to accomplish that task.  The only difference between what you will use, and what the screenshot indicates, is you should use a different disklabel.

[image]

Comment: Also, I cant free up the necessary space to run that program it needs 8gb but I only have 6 free. it hence why I got the bigger hard drive

Comment: The Rufus settings apply to both Windows 7 and Windows 10.  There is no solution to your space issue other than making space for it.  You should not need more than the size of the ISO.